# Keep chrome extension running when focus lost

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, recordrtc

I have a chrome extension that records a user's microphone when they click a button. Unfortunately, when they click anything else outside the chrome extension popup, the extension 'unmounts' and therefore microphone recording stops.

This is clearly not something I want from a chrome extension that is supposed to record someone's microphone.

Is there a hack that will allow me to keep recording?

Comment: Do the recording in the background page or event page, see [architecture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch).

Comment: @wOxxOm That looks like exactly what I need. I will give it a go today. Thanks.